# Using Microsoft Tier Interaction Profiler with MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012

Does the Visual Studio 2012 Tiered Interaction Profiler (TIP) work with the MySQL connector?

I'm trying to profile a C# applications use of a MySQL Database.  Unfortunately attempts to use the built in Tier Interaction Profiler haven't worked.  The "Tier Interaction" isn't included in the analysis report drop down.

My understanding of the profiler is that the connection uses an ADO.NET connector.  Currently, I've tried:

1. Using the MySQL connector v6.8.0 as a direct download.
2. Using community installed which adds the Visual Studio components missing since v6.7

To ensure it wasn't an issue with Visual Studio I've tried it with an another application that uses an SQL Server database and it works correctly.

If it's of any relevance I'm using Windows 8.1.